# How do I select a closest ancestor plus the ancestor's next?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using jQuery to manipulate table rows that are paired within a table.  I'm trying to select rows based on found items from my previous jQuery where if the row contains a visible image, I need that row *and* it's next sibling.  I can get the row using:

```
$("img[src*='file.png']:not(:hidden)").closest("tr");
```

Because I'm also after the sibling row, it seemed logical to me that the next selector would work:

```
$("img[src*='file.png']:not(:hidden)").closest("tr+next");
```

The first query produces the first row of the pair, but the second query returns nothing.  Am I misinterpreting the documentation - I thought the selector was:

```
$("prev+next");
```

I obviously seem to be missing something here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var temp;
temp = $('whatever').closest('tr').add( temp.next() )
```

Also

```
var temp = $('whatever').closest('tr'); temp = temp.next().andSelf()
```

Comment: That does return the ancestor's next sibling but not the ancestor itself, I need both together.

Comment: That could work... it seems a bit long winded.  But in a pinch, I may end up using this.

Comment: $('whatever').closest('tr').next().andSelf() should therefore work omitting the need for temp...

Comment: And what was that? I would think `andSelf` referred to the initial object and not the `.closest` so your `$('whatever').closest('tr').next().andSelf()` will probably return `whatever`, I could be wrong.

Comment: It *appears* from my testing that it works on the result of .closest() not the result of the initial object.

Comment: that was the very first thing I thought of, too but I dismissed it because I didnt think it returned the `prevObj`. Guess I was wrong, didn't expect that level of magic.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but what about?

$("img[src*='file.png']:not(:hidden)").closest("tr+tr");

Comment: Haha, don't tell me I interpreted the documentation too literally? LOL... If that's it, I'm going to go and drown myself :P

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it should work, but only appears to return the first row of the pair.

Comment: I think it's interpreting this as find the closest "tr+tr", of course there is no closest "tr+tr", in the absence of that, I think I need .closest ("tr").add($(this).next()) as suggested by @meder